# syntax error in mysql procedure error code 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write one procedure, i am getting syntax error. I was trying to fix the same with the help of net, but failed.

Here is my stored procedure. Any help please?

The scenario is i am trying to take workspaceid  column values from table hotelings and trying to make that value as my column for another table. Then i am trying to update the same column value with ; for a given start and end time of hoteling table in newly created  table2.

My two tables are

```
CREATE TABLE `hotelings` (
  `HotelingId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` longtext,
  `StartDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `EndDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `BookedBy` longtext,
  `BookingType` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RepeatType` longtext,
  `RepeatDay` longtext,
  `ProjectId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `WorkSpaceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `starttime` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endtime` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`HotelingId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE `hotelingtime` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and my procedure is:

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
    BEGIN

    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'MAX(CASE WHEN workspaceid = ''',
          workspaceid,
          ''' then "" ELSE NULL end) AS ',
          CONCAT('`',workspaceid,'`')
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    FROM sms.hotelings;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS SELECT t.Time as Time, ', @sql, ' FROM sms.hotelings h, sms.hotelingtime t 
                       GROUP BY t.Time');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    begin
    declare num_rows int;
    declare i int;
    declare col_name varchar(50);
    declare v varchar(10); 
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    -- cursor to fetch column names
    DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
      SELECT column_name
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE table_name = 'table2'
      ORDER BY ordinal_position; 
        -- declare NOT FOUND handler
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
            FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

        OPEN col_names;

        temp_hotelingloop: LOOP

            FETCH col_names INTO col_name;

            IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE temp_hotelingloop;
            END IF;

    begin
    declare starttime time;
    declare endtime time;

    -- cursor to fetch start and end for a given workspaceid
    DECLARE startendTime CURSOR FOR
      SELECT starttime, endtime from hotelings
    where workspaceid = col_name;

     OPEN startendTime;
     FETCH startendTime INTO starttime, endtime;

-- i am getting error here and not giving me the result. 
    SET @sql = CONCAT('update table2 set ''',@col_name ,''' = '';'' where time between ''',@starttime,''' and ''',@endtime,'''');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    CLOSE startendTime;
    end;
        SET i = i + 1;  

         END LOOP temp_hotelingloop;

        CLOSE col_names;

    end;
     select * from table2;
    DROP  TABLE table2;

    END
```

Any help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you assigning ';' to columns. But what if the column is INT or DATETIME?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('update table2 set ''',@col_name ,''' = '';'' where time between ''',@starttime,''' and ''',@endtime,'''');
```

You are using @col_name here, but on your declaration missing the @

```
declare col_name varchar(50);
```

Comment: declare col_name varchar(50);

you need to declare @col_name varchar(50); if you want to use the @ or remove it on your query

Comment: i want to substitue the cursor result col_name as parameter. so i used @col_name, i tried giving the col_name directly then also i am getting error

Comment: try put all your col_name ==> @col_name, same goes to starttime/endtime ==> @starttime/@endtime

Comment: sorry i didnt get you

Comment: col_name is different with @col_name

Comment: you declared col_name but using @col_name, so all col_name need to change to (@col_name)